# o-genki desu de or odaijini?

Tags: word-choice

I'd like to find the difference between the two. Can anyone tell me when to use which?

Comment: "o-genki desu de" makes no sense. As words of farewell, did you mean "o-genki de"?

Comment: I think this is a dupe of the linked question, but if you can't read hiragana/kanji please let us know.